# How to make all ggplot barplot appear

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have plotted a bar chart with `ggplot2` using different responses ("Don't Know", "Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree"), however the bar for "Dont Know" is not appearing on the plot. How can I fix this?

```
data<-read.csv (file ="Book2.CSV", header = T)
Frequency<-data$QLO
Affiliation<- factor(data$Affiliation, labels = c("Food", "racing","football", "basketball"))
Response <- factor (data$QLO, labels = c("Don't Know", "Disagree","Agree", "Strongly Agree")) 

df<- data.frame(Frequency, Affilation, Response)

df2<- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Affiliation, y=Frequency, fill=Response))

df2 + geom_bar(stat="identity",position = "dodge",  width=0.75,alpha=0.5, lwd=0.5) + 
     ggtitle(" what do you like)") + 
     theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 9, face = "bold")) + 
     scale_x_discrete(drop=F)
```

[image: Image of Bar Chart]

Comment: How many are you expecting to be labeled "Don't Know"? Have you checked your dataframe to make sure there are actually responses that match this?

Comment: Yes, I did I have code "Don't Know"? as 0 "Disagree" =1,"Agree" =2, "Strongly Agree=3"))

Comment: @David_David I meant do you actually have responses that correspond to "Don't Know"? How many per category? A bar won't appear if there are 0 responses (as seems to be the case for "Disagree" in most of your categories).

Comment: Can you share your dataframe, `df`?  To do so, please copy and paste the output of `dput(df)` into your question.